# adsense in flash/as3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, load, adsense

I'm trying to load some adsense ads in my flash file. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

Does it specifically have to be adsense? MochiMedia has a similar ad network setup specifically made for Flash.

Answer (score 0):

By the way MochiMedia ad solution is targeted to flash game developers and not every flash project.
To see a 35 minute video that digs into the details of implementation(very easy)

check out this free video course and sample game:

http://everythingfla.com/course/mochiads

I've been looking for a supported solution for google adsence as well for my site but it looks like google is in an early beta that only takes flash video sites with a very large amount of trafic:
http://www.google.com/ads/videoadsolutions/publisher.html

but i couldn't find any solution that actually works and can be integrated in any flash content unrelevent to the type of content involved.

Comment: I know that mochiads are just for game developers...I thought that is another viable/easy way to do it. Thanks ;)